# How can I fix a "bad message" in NixOS?

Tags: nix, nixos

This is what happens when I run `nix-collect-garbage`:

```
jon@jon-laptop ~> nix-collect-garbage -d
removing old generations of profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/jon/profile
removing old generations of profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/jon/home-manager
removing old generations of profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/jon/channels
finding garbage collector roots...
0 store paths deleted, 0.00 MiB freed
error: --- Error ---------------------------------------------------------------- nix-collect-garbage
reading directory '/nix/store/trash/apni99c9rdaii9xvsmf1x65dvwgsaxj0-sqlite-3.33.0-bin/share/man': Bad message
```

How can I fix this? I can't just delete the offending directory, apparently, since it tells me it's a read-only filesystem.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Probably best to create an [issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/new).

Comment: Definitely stange. Is your disk close to full by chance? This can cause weird issues with garbage collection.